# Add delay to "_on" mouseenter

Tags: javascript, jquery, delay, settimeout, mouseenter

I want to add a delay on this mouseenter shown below. Can anybody help me with this "_on" method, pls? I tried with setTimeout, but it won't work.

This is the code:

```
declareEvents: function () {   
                var me = this,
                $el;

                $.each(me._$listItems, function (i, el) {
                    $el = $(el);    
                me._on($el, 'mouseenter', $.proxy(me.onListItemEnter, me, i, $el));
},
```

What I've tried:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    me._on($el, 'mouseenter', $.proxy(me.onListItemEnter, me, i, $el));
}, 1000);
```

And:

```
me._on($el, 'mouseenter', setTimeout(function() {
    $.proxy(me.onListItemEnter, me, i, $el);
}, 1000);
```

Thank you very much for you help!

Comment: Is `_on` part of a library you're using?

Comment: Yes, I am usind jQuery UI

Comment: Don't listen to any events on the items itself, but on their parent. And you are looking at a simple [debounce](http://davidwalsh.name/javascript-debounce-function) function.

Answer (score 3):

You should wrap handler in anonymous function and clear any previous timeout:

```
me._on($el, 'mouseenter', function () {
    clearTimeout($(this).data('timeout'));
    $(this).data('timeout' , setTimeout(function () {
        $.proxy(me.onListItemEnter, me, i, $el);
    }, 1000));
});
```

And maybe clear timeout on `mouseleave` too.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, unfortunately it don't work for me. I put more from the code in my Question, maybe it will help to figure out my problem.

Comment: @user3009162 Does the original code, without the delay, work?

Comment: @user3009162 You should provide sample which replicates your issue as e.g a jsFiddle

Answer (score 1):

[jQuery UI's code](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/ui/widget.js#L567-L574) has an example of setting multiple events using `_on` in a widget. This will allow you to easily remove the timeout on `mouseleave`, as A. Wolff suggested.

```js
declareEvents: function() {
  var me = this;

  $.each(me._$listItems, function(i, el) {
    var $el = $(el);
    clearTimeout($el.data("hoverTimeout"));

    me._on($el, {
      mouseenter: function () {
        $el.data("hoverTimeout", setTimeout($.proxy(me.onListItemEnter, me, i, $el)));
      },
      mouseleave: function () {
        clearTimeout($el.data("hoverTimeout"));
      },
    });

  });
}
```